# Matching small grayscale images

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching

I want to test whether two images match. Partial matches also interest me.
The problem is that the images suffer from strong noise. Another problem is that the images might be rotated with an unknown angle. The objects shown in the images will roughly always have the same scale!

The images show area scans from a top-shot perspective. "Lines" are mostly walls and other objects are mostly trees and different kinds of plants.

[image]
[image]

Another problem was, that the left image was very blurry and the right one's lines were very thin.
To compensate for this difference I used dilation. The resulting images are the ones I uploaded.

Although It can easily be seen that these images match almost perfectly I cannot convince my algorithm of this fact.

My first idea was a feature based matching, but the matches are horrible. It only worked for a rotation angle of -90°, 0° and 90°. Although most descriptors are rotation invariant (in past projects they really were), the rotation invariance seems to fail for this example.

My second idea was to split the images into several smaller segments and to use template matching. So I segmented the images and, again, for the human eye they are pretty easy to match. The goal of this step was to segment the different walls and trees/plants.

[image]

The upper row are parts of the left, and the lower are parts of the right image. After the segmentation the segments were dilated again.

As already mentioned: Template matching failed, as did contour based template matching and contour matching.

I think the dilation of the images was very important, because it was nearly impossible for the human eye to match the segments without dilation before the segmentation. Another dilation after the segmentation made this even less difficult.

Answer (score 4):

Your first job should be to fix the orientation. I am not sure what is the best algorithm to do that but here is an approach I would use: fix one of the images and start rotating the other. For each rotation compute a histogram for the color intense on each of the rows/columns. Compute some distance between the resulting vectors(e.g. use cross product). Choose the rotation that results in smallest cross product. It may be good idea to combine this approach with [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).

Once you have the images aligned in approximately the same direction, I believe matching should be easier. As the two images are supposed to be at the same scale, compute something analogous to the geometrical center for both images: compute weighted sum of all pixels - a completely white pixel would have a weight of 1, and a completely black - weight 0, the sum should be a vector of size 2(x and y coordinate). After that divide those values by the dimensions of the image and call this "geometrical center of the image". Overlay the two images in a way that the two centers coincide and then once more compute cross product for the difference between the images. I would say this should be their difference.

Comment: So you do suggest to match the images without segmenting them first, don't you?

What about a translation? I think my two sample pictures will match almost perfectly, but in case there is only a partial match, can I also fix the orientation the way you described it?

Comment: This depends on the way images are obtained. I believe my approach will only work if white areas are distributed approximately the same way. If that is not the case maybe you could use Hough transform to fix orientation?

Comment: I am also not saying that segmentation is a bad approach. I simply propose alternative solution.

Comment: I like the idea about fixing the orientation, but I do not understand the part about the matching. Will it work if there is only a partial match?

The white areas which are supposed to match, are distributed approximately the same way, except for some noise or a small deformation of a "wall" if an object e.g. a person, stands next to it.

Didn't want to make it sound like you don't like the segmentation approach. No offense.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try following methods to find rotation and similarity.

- Use image moments to get the rotation as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment).
- Once you rotate the image, use cross-correlation to evaluate the similarity.

EDIT

I tried this with OpenCV and C++ for the two sample images. I'm posting the code and results below as it seems to work well at least for the given samples.

Here's the function to calculate the orientation vector using image moments:

```
Mat orientVec(Mat& im)
{
    Moments m = moments(im);
    double cov[4] = {m.mu20/m.m00, m.mu11/m.m00, m.mu11/m.m00, m.mu02/m.m00};
    Mat covMat(2, 2, CV_64F, cov);
    Mat evals, evecs;
    eigen(covMat, evals, evecs);

    return evecs.row(0);
}
```

Rotate and match sample images:

```
    Mat im1 = imread(INPUT_FOLDER_PATH + string("WojUi.png"), 0);
    Mat im2 = imread(INPUT_FOLDER_PATH + string("XbrsV.png"), 0);

    // get the orientation vector
    Mat v1 = orientVec(im1);
    Mat v2 = orientVec(im2);

    double angle = acos(v1.dot(v2))*180/CV_PI;
    // rotate im2. try rotating with -angle and +angle. here using -angle
    Mat rot = getRotationMatrix2D(Point(im2.cols/2, im2.rows/2), -angle, 1.0);
    Mat im2Rot;
    warpAffine(im2, im2Rot, rot, Size(im2.rows, im2.cols));

    // add a border to rotated image
    int borderSize = im1.rows > im2.cols ? im1.rows/2 + 1 : im1.cols/2 + 1;
    Mat im2RotBorder;
    copyMakeBorder(im2Rot, im2RotBorder, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, 
        BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    // normalized cross-correlation
    Mat& image = im2RotBorder;
    Mat& templ = im1;
    Mat nxcor;
    matchTemplate(image, templ, nxcor, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);

    // take the max
    double max;
    Point maxPt;
    minMaxLoc(nxcor, NULL, &max, NULL, &maxPt);

    // draw the match
    Mat rgb;
    cvtColor(image, rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    rectangle(rgb, maxPt, Point(maxPt.x+templ.cols-1, maxPt.y+templ.rows-1), Scalar(0, 255, 255), 2);

    cout << "max: " << max << endl;
```

With -angle rotation in code, I get max = 0.758. Below is the rotated image in this case with the matching region.

[image]

Otherwise max = 0.293